# creating a page based on a field

Tags: javascript

In my form I have a total field which is the sum of several checkboxes. When it reaches 21 total page one must be created. below the code, which worked well in another case and this time it gives me a syntax error. someone there you an idea ??

Thank you in advance

```
    this.getField("TOTAL").value =
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.0").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.1").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.2").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.3").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.4").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.5").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.6").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.7").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.8").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.9").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.10").value +  
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.11").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.12").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.13").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.14").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.15").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.16").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.17").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.18").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.19").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.20").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.21").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.22").value +  
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.23").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.24").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.25").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.26").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.27").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.28").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.29").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.30").value +
  this.getField("P6eval_competences.manageriales.31").value;

if (getField("TOTAL").value == "21") {
  var expTplt = getTemplate("NIVEAU MATURE");
  expTplt.spawn(numPages, true, false);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order for others to help you out please specify the error message which you get.

Comment: "this time it gives me a syntax error", please specify what syntax error

Comment: Merci pour votre rapidité. le message est Sy,taxError:missing } in compound statement 36: to the line 37

Comment: Looks like there is a "this." missing before getField in if (getField("TOTAL").value == "21")

Comment: I just did the tests, it does not matter, I'm turning it every way I can not find

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use parseInt() method cause the values which are returned are not Integer rather they are Strings.

Comment: This method works with three summed values. And there is no syntax error.
I am new, so I do not know your proposal

Comment: My point is that you are trying to calculate the sum but the values returned by the fields aren't number that can be  add. If you want to add the value  then you should make the values integer to add them.